# height is increasing automatically of div with contenteditable="true"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've div with property `contenteditable="true"`.

```
<div contenteditable="true" class="textarea"></div>
```

**Requirements** 
1. Text should be center aligned vertically and horizontally.
2. Height should not increase automatically with increase in content inside that div, if content increases inside div, scrollbar need to display.

Here is [js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rduD2/1/)

if you want, use jquery too.

Comment: i dont think contenteditable will let you do that. instead, you can wrap that contenteditable div inside of another div, and when the contenteditable expands, it will cause its parent to scroll. its why wysiwig editors like tiny mce get wrapped by iframes i think

Comment: i'm trying but still no result

Comment: height problem can be solved by position:absolute; but with this text is not vertically center aligned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap the contenteditable div in 2 containers, one for the width and height with `overflow:auto;` and one for the `display-table;` property so the text is horzontaly centered :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/rduD2/7/)**

*HTML :*

```
<div class="container1">
    <div class="container2">
        <div contenteditable="true" class="textarea"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

*CSS :*

```
.container1{
    height:60px;
    width:273px; 
    overflow:auto;
    border:1px solid green;
}
.container2 {
    min-height:100%;

    display:table;
}
.textarea {
    width:273px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 18px;
    outline: none;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-user-select: text;
    -moz-user-select: text;
    -ms-user-select: text;
    user-select: text;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: still text is not vertically center

Comment: @sirajpathan You are right, but if you add an other container it works as you desire : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/rduD2/7/ I'll edit my post with this solution

Answer (score 0):

When u dont specify a height it will automatically grow vertically when more information is added into the div tage. But i think you will have to make sure the content is absolute and/or you can try this simple code to see if it helps

Try this, CSS code.

```
.scroll {
width:100px;
height:100px;
overflow:scroll;
}
```

HTML code

```
<div class="scroll">
SOME TEXT HERE.SOME TEXT HERE.SOME TEXT HERE.SOME TEXT HERE.SOME TEXT HERE.SOME TEXT HERE. SOME TEXT HERE.SOME TEXT HERE.SOME TEXT HERE.SOME TEXT HERE.SOME TEXT HERE.SOME TEXT HERE.SOME TEXT HERE.SOME TEXT HERE.SOME TEXT HERE.SOME TEXT HERE.SOME TEXT HERE.SOME TEXT HERE.
</div>
```